# is it possible if round robin scheduling not have time quantum or burst time?

Tags: java

i need help. i have implement round-robin algorithm in java coding like the following coding but it is not have burst time and time quantum. is it possible if round-robin not have busrt time and time quantum? Additional question, is it true a round-robin i implement?

```
@Override
public Vm getVmToOffload(Task task, int deviceId) {
    Vm selectedVM = null;

    if (deviceId == SimSettings.MOBILE_DATACENTER_ID) {
        // Select VM on the mobile data center
        List<MobileVM> vmArray = SimManager.getInstance().getMobileServerManager().getVmList(task.getMobileDeviceId());
        double requiredCapacity = ((CpuUtilizationModel_Custom) task.getUtilizationModelCpu()).predictUtilization(vmArray.get(0).getVmType());
        double targetVmCapacity = (double) 100 - vmArray.get(0).getCloudletScheduler().getTotalUtilizationOfCpu(CloudSim.clock());

        if (requiredCapacity <= targetVmCapacity)
            selectedVM = vmArray.get(0);
    } else if (deviceId == SimSettings.GENERIC_EDGE_DEVICE_ID) {
        // Select VM on edge devices via Round Robin algorithm
        List<EdgeVM> vmList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int hostIndex = 0; hostIndex < numberOfHost; hostIndex++) {
            vmList.addAll(SimManager.getInstance().getEdgeServerManager().getVmList(hostIndex));
        }

        // Find the next available VM using Round Robin
        int currentIndex = task.getCloudletId() % vmList.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < vmList.size(); i++) {
            EdgeVM vm = vmList.get(currentIndex);
            double requiredCapacity = ((CpuUtilizationModel_Custom) task.getUtilizationModelCpu()).predictUtilization(vm.getVmType());
            double targetVmCapacity = (double) 100 - vm.getCloudletScheduler().getTotalUtilizationOfCpu(CloudSim.clock());

            if (requiredCapacity <= targetVmCapacity) {
                selectedVM = vm;
                break;
            }

            currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % vmList.size(); // Move to the next VM in a circular manner
        }
    } else {
        SimLogger.printLine("Unknown device id! The simulation has been terminated.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    return selectedVM;
}
```

I expected i implement the round-robin algorithm correctly. Besides, i implement this algorithm in EdgeCloudSim simulator. Any help appreciated.